# Airflow instantly drops dag when using telegram operator and AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator

Tags: airflow

trying to set up a simple telegram notification, dag instantly fails without logs, if I use any operator other than airbyte, everything works fine, if I remove the telegram operator still works fine, the code below, does anyone know what the cause may be?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.airbyte.operators.airbyte import AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator
from airflow.providers.telegram.operators.telegram import TelegramOperator

def on_fail_callback(context):
    send_message = TelegramOperator(
        task_id='send_message_telegram',
        telegram_conn_id='telegram_id',
        chat_id='-1001426579030',
        text=f"""
            \ud83d\ude21 Task has failed.
            Task: {context.get('task_instance').task_id}  
            DAG: {context.get('task_instance').dag_id} 
            Execution Time: {context.get('execution_date')}
            Exception: {context.get('exception')}
            """,
        dag=dag)
    return send_message.execute(context=context)

with DAG(dag_id='trigger_airbyte_exchangerates',
         default_args={'owner': 'airflow'},
         schedule_interval="30 0 * * *",
         on_failure_callback=on_fail_callback,
         start_date=days_ago(1)
    ) as dag:

    exchangerates_to_bq = AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator(
        task_id='airbyte_exchangerates',
        airbyte_conn_id='Airbyte',
        connection_id='3ab557d2-7a00-4c09-8437-003be6c0b274',
        asynchronous=False,
        timeout=3600,
        wait_seconds=3
    )
```

With other operators, messages to telegram come instantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't use AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator.
But, if i need telegram notification, when the task is broken, i use:

```
send_telegram_message = TelegramOperator(
        task_id='send_telegram_message',
        telegram_conn_id='Telegram',
        chat_id='',
        text='',
        dag=dag,
        trigger_rule='one_failed'
    )
```

And then:
[list_all_my_task] >> send_telegram_message

A telegram message will be sent only, when one of the top tasks is broken. Otherwise telegram notification is skipped. Use 'trigger_rule'.